# How do companies like walmart,target etc. update there barcode scanner systems? or create a barcode system?

Tags: networking, database

I was wondering how a big company make a barcode system? Are there any barcode databases off the web that I could just download as a whole? And once I had one where would I go  to update the already existing database?

Comment: They start by creating the database, then they write the software to put on the scanners, then they connect the two.  Sounds like you need to do additional research.

Comment: creating the database do you know where they load this data from?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1050194/1338846 is about ready-made databases. However, every company must decide how they do it, there's many paths to the goal and methods often depends on predefined requirements.

Comment: could you give a single path for a lay person

Comment: @Andrew - A lay person won't be able to do what you want.  Companies simply load their data from their stock.  The simplest way is to scan a single item of a particular stock number and set the price.

Answer (score 2):

> Are there any barcode databases off the web that I could just download
> as a whole?

Yes there are, take a look at question asked on StackOverflow:
[Database of commercial barcodes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1050194/1338846)

It is all about ready-made databases. However, every company must decide how they do it, there's many paths to the goal and methods often depends on predefined requirements.

It seems that [http://gepir.gs1.org](http://gepir.gs1.org/) has comprehensive database but I dont know if it is open for anyone. See another link for more of them.

> Creating the database do you know where they load this data from?

They might *"load"* data from list of received goods :) Usually there's someone doing inquiries and orders, that guy already works on product database and therefore may as well enter new, update existing and remove obsolote data to/from database.

#### Final words...

There is no just one correct path to achieve so broad goal. Maybe you could provide some more information by [edinting your question](https://superuser.com/posts/590751/edit) and explaining better what are you trying to accomplish.